# How to increase the max size of a template/list without stsadm or powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin

I've looked around but haven't found a solution. Is there a way to increase the size of a template beyond 52428800 bytes without using powershell or stsadm? I don't have access to either, and I'm attempting to move a list with all the properties (columns, etc) intact by saving it as a template. I don't have access to central administration either.

Or if there is an alternative way of moving a list without using templates that would also be very helpful!

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: This is a different site collection.

Comment: within site collection or different site collections?

Comment: Different site collection, sorry I should have specified. I will edit it

Comment: Any ideas Waqas?

Comment: As @WaqasSarwarMCSE said, what you're asking to do has to be done with server access. However, there might be other means to your end goal. If you save the list as a template *without content* it probably won't exceed the size limit. Then you can copy and paste over content (if there are no attachments) in datasheet view, or using CSOM or SPServices.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do it without accessing the server. You have to access the PowerShell or Stsadm to perform this activity.

Or export / Import.

Everything you will be get needs a server side access. check the answer here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9cbed62e-badd-48da-874e-945d4eec39fb/increasing-site-template-size?forum=sharepointgeneral